# gpg equivalent of ssh-add?

Tags: server, gnupg

I'm trying to use a passphrase-protected GPG key with Obnam, which invokes `gpg` (1.4.x on Ubuntu Server 14.04) in batch mode. `gpg` can't ask for the password in batch mode. All `gpg-agent` stuff that I find seems to involve a GUI dialog, but I'm using Ubuntu Server over ssh and the server doesn't have x.org installed.

What's a non-GUI equivalent of `ssh-add` for GPG? That is, it'd like to invoke something that works in the terminal to cache the passphrase or the unlocked key in RAM and then invoke `obnam`, which in turn invokes `gpg` in batch mode, and have this work.

Comment: The default `gpg` and `gpg-agent` password dialogues should be on the command line anyway – no X.org required. You can also [forward your local GPG agent](//superuser.com/q/161973).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install `pinentry-curses` and then install `gnupg-agent`. Create a file called `gpg-agent.conf` inside your `GNUPG_HOME` directory (usually `~/.gnupg`) and put something like

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
default-cache-ttl 31536000
default-cache-ttl-ssh 31536000
max-cache-ttl 31536000
max-cache-ttl-ssh 31536000
```

in the file. (The numbers are cache validity durations in seconds.)

Then, to cache the unlocked key, run

```
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
eval "$(gpg-agent --daemon)"
```

followed by some `gpg` operation that requires the key to be unlocked.